# Css Position Sticky, but I would like it to show the entire content of the element

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my webpage with `position:sticky; top : 0;` , as expected it is sticking to the top of the page when it reaches there. It works fine on desktop. But on mobile devices, the content of the div is longer than its height. But since it is sticking, its not showing the content that is beyond the screen height of the device. What should be done next to make the div scrollable and only stick once the entire content is shown?
Thank you.

Comment: _"What should be done next to make the div scrollable"_ - give it a `max-height`, and `overflow: auto`? _"and only stick once the entire content is shown"_ - not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) to provide a custom CSS for mobile. For example change font size, give the element `overflow: scroll` or whatever you want the design to be like. You could also compare the height of that div with the window height on every [window resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) and apply the appropriate styling you want.

Comment: the element is sticking when the top of the element is reaching the top of the viewport, instead, i would like the element to stick/freeze when the bottom of the element reaches the bottom of the view port

Comment: Have you tried positioning by bottom rather than top?

Comment: yes, positioning it at bottom makes it stick only while scrolling in upwards direction. Exactly the opposite of the sticky at top. So, its not working.

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to what is wanted. If its top isn't to stick to the top or its bottom isn't to stick to the bottom, what part of the element is to stick to where?

Comment: i want the bottom to stick to the bottom of viewport while scrolling toward the end of page. (the position sticky, bottom will only stick the bottom of the element to bottom of viewport only while scrolling towards the starting of the page)